# reading xml image data with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have just got an xml file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <somenamespace xmlns="http://...">

   <Image type="jpeg">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAwADAAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCADwAUADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDMwM8daXkClVMZNOAycCthkLoGBzVD7IVYsCcVq4OcVEQNxBPfFJsLGFeaYtzy3JFc5NafZ7vC5PtXesgUHHpWHcWbSXWeKhpMRXsUyASK3IkCgGqsVqVxV6JDtqo6BLUUjgVImdvNIqHdUgFWhAVBpQMGnAZNO2H0qybgqbs80j43cVKoxxTtq+goC5XANWACcVIEXFKF2n2piH7fk201V6AVIBk4qUKFHFIaDGVxUEsGR8tWBknipAnHNFxlAQ7T0NSiLvmp2UCkHIzQA0LmnbM/So5GKngVH5vye4pFEroAQRUe8I3NQrK7PgHFSNHIwzQMJGV0PSq6ooPFS+WQ2CaesDZFK4EDRN68U3yV6sa0CpVMHnioChzjmkmUSQxK6EdKoz2wWXOehq0u9T8tNdS3Ud6LDZJBc7FAxVS8cTFuBTzwcU3YWzT5RczKRgBPWmNbgc5rUEXy56VXkhI6VQNlBY+elO8rdjirZiAxUTMAMCpYriKuwHP6VHK4wKV2bFQSKWHWkHMaarjvmnU1Bkjn86U5BpIqwuABVZwGJ+tT+ZgjIqKTAOR1qWgsOjhD8Himz26RYPHNOjm2DOOaz7zUA9wEA6UhWJCueRTo8jrSRcqKlCjOatIljgMU9Y+PSmDJ6VIpIOD6U0SPHWn0irk1Iqc81SExgFPCknvj6VIFyeAKmEeBk9adxWI9m0cDigkDipwpOOelQTjLdMc9aAFVxkVaChhVWBMrntVkNg0gQg+Q8VIrbh1zSqmV5pCmDwaCkxGXNVXk2Nt3Ac1Yk3HhCM1XazlkbdgUbFJXI55ONwNUzOemPxxWmLF1YLgGri6QrgMe/tUuQ1EwVm2tnrWlZziVMEge1W/7HjjYkt+GKhmtlhYNGOtG4WsQ7MTZ7Zq8m0jgiq8UTEZNWo48U7XE2NMefpUToo4Iq0QKgeMlutOwkyGKJQScc0kgUH7tTLGVPWnNGCM5oHcz/KDNnHFSrCiAnHapQmD7U9l+Un2piKxTpioJuBg1eG0deKqzoJDgVPUCiTgVAy7TVtoihxUDAFhTYFd1LdqrGJ3YgZxWq6J5eQarAYOai3YCdB8oqQNjqKiDe/FPHNSmWmRySLu4607G4c0rxgkCpo0wgAouO9ypJiKJia598Pclge9dBqZ2wEVkWkQZmqXoMt2zA7RV8r8nSqsEAVgauheK1jsZyI1B7VJsPcU9AM0rqSRiqJCP7wxVmOPnOKrxArJyOK0YzxQKw0RnHSgqR2qYDmlY47Z+lCAiWPjFBiJ7A08OD7U6mIYNqDBGPamAFjwKnKBu5puCh45FCQrkSy4faelTSY25FU5sg5FRtcMExxQNMsI5GTxUn2olgqDk1RtzvmEZJwea3BZRrFvDZ9QTUySRUWSWy5Abb1q80qrGcdR7VmfaNgwMYpiys+KlRuacyRJLKzPx+dQshbGas+Wqj3phU+hrRRsZuTYsaDZ0FNZSvPapI1IzSuuR05piuQDpTJOwqRtyjimIrOTn6UAIu4+hpTgDmpCm3rUbqDzmk0BGFHJpGHykUoyDnBoPJ96AuV2VhxgU1yFGavCLK+tVLuPCcVIyk5zk9qpshdvlq6EZu2aeluq5J602CMqSFwOv61LHavsBGKmmbDnH6VGJ2jI29KkdxqgjrUicnFS7FycCpI4VHNRYCIKB1qVSBipDCpHpUTjYcA54pBdlLVNrRqPWs6zTk4rTlhEqjd1FMjt1jPFO12NSJI1wtSUKhPSpgMcVqtEQ3dkaqcipNvOaFxUjDYRii4DwgK9Pzp8QwQPSlTLipUUD60gHUBSM80/Y3XFDISOlNITITg8ipV5AqNo2UdDT489qZI5VO7Jp/Bp2GxTlXPWmhFeWLI9qy54mViW/CuhEa46VSvINynA/GgVzDjDGbepwRV838gTa3zfSohEYSQv60JA0j5KnrU2uzXZD47zewXFbECjYD7VXisIggYLz9asRjaMDpVIlolAHWn9uRUsSKRk09wuMA81S1DoVgM0uMUvQ8etOdgVGKdkBGyhiKY42rgcU/Jzj9aaRuAzSYFdmBOMU4Rhxn0p5h78ZpCpC8VI7jKaUBbNBJXnqKjZyTxxQBL5oAxVOc7jjPWpGyQcdajQMZOecetSykRnCDB7UyRvlNWp4gUBxWe5+bGc0kBVckNSsFYdOan8tXx3NJJGseOf0pgPjA5JqUGo0I24zRIdsTEMOhrJM0aI7mfbhQee9RxsXUN7Vky3S+bgvV+3kDoMHtVENE+cHmlCbiMGm7M8mpowBVdDNj1TAx3p3lsaerBcE1Ip3NxSBMg8srg0/IZcd6leJivFRIhLUASRnacc8VOvzDNRBcNg1OmKEF7Ey46A048daavWpCBitEFyMndxTQoBp4GDT1C561RNwB4oztNLx0FIemMU7C5hxfK+lQPyppzNtFRFyaVguJ5QfqODTxEFHH5URnHWjzfmwKLIVwLsBwMCnxzcgEU0KSx3dPephEo5OBUgWI3x1p7Dd7VB16VMqkdTmhDuAwM1G65Yc1Kq7nxgU8gKRVXGiNkBwc9qgcEDA61YMg3d6PLDfNk81BZXVSOT1pcnnI4p5Qr1pG4U/SmIqyYwar1JJgtVKd8Y+tIZZBXuahllVOVxmqgcuDyRzT4gNpzzzzmkxkolaQYPSqcy4OKs+YMkY6VVuJOenehASWrAZLEVXvZl38HFRPGzIcdagNs4XcTxQUXw3Sq97deXbsF64NWInSROKoXcYL+1c6kbtGCoknm3McfStGFni6HIqyEjC4A5qCJWEvI4qeZ3BxVjQgufMXnGRxVqNstVeGAyLxirCQOvIx+FaxkYSiSknNWoAWPNUQH8wZHeryPtbAqrkNWJJW2jnpSRYJzTZDnk9KdGucEdKBExTcOfWmMdh4p5U7Rmk8ugGOST1qUOMfeqtjBpScCq5mQyyCCKcMVXjfAqUSCtIiZIpw2DSE5OaY0iqMk1Sk1KNDgtVBc0MZHNRyLs6Vn/2zbqPvE1G+rxyD5T+dAjUj6HJFIFTfWHLr0cYIH0qlJrpZvlzTugOrLgHB496glvFQ4zXKPrkqg5D4rPbWDIxGTmp5kGp3UF/83OMetaMd2jnAIz9a84jv3lYAA56Vt2dtqIHmxqWA7ZqXJMdmdkrrkHPemySFjxWNbXkyMFnjKnOOa0fOVhwQKAuTbiO9KHI57elRg5FL1FA07D/ADT6Go3Y00AqeuaY7ZHFAytIuWqBkVmw3IqyVI5NVnYBsj1oZQjqkaDiqjZGTjAqxIwkXmoZD+6x1qCrkYkycAcUyUc5oiBaTJ4waWdgz8DirQDQcRn1pGm3R7BTJTtWoYn+bntQFx9vEYu5p8kYl470iy/LkilQnzMgVxHTcrm0dX6HFWVteA2zmtJAGUEqM0Sfc4pDuVYBtOMVciALYNQBOhzU0Z+aqRDJvJB5x3qtKpR/QVdR+MYqldMd3Tg1aMpIVT5xGTx6VZixHxVeGM7A2etWEhJG4HmnclInxuGO1QtlWwKkVtijdQcMciqQmQd8mo5pti/LyasvGWUGoWiGD600TYjtZmkB3ZzS3UyQJvZsfWpfssiR+YAQKxdVl8xNmeAauLIYy41MyMVV/wAqz5Q7EHdyajhxv659asSgYyOtTKTKjFFNrcgk7zUEjNGBgn29quOpIqpInFRzA0VSzMfnYnmnRriQemaayHPB4pVD5AUEk8Ck5FqJauBujwoOcViGCVZiWXFdClldIm6RMCnHTDIMhWzjOaXMPlZjwyNGwK54Oa7PQPEscJ2TqOnJNc42kOZQuSAauSaK1vEZFZmI65quYVmdxPqum3cZCFNx46dKhhs2my0TnaB1FeelnjkBViK6bS/EclvFtbkGtIzI5TbW5EEghlfDj9auCUMM9R61xd7fPdXXnJxg1qaVqWY9knY1XNcVjoZASMgcVCMAkmnrKGTtUZG4mmBFLICDz+tUup61tQWMbJlgDn1qjLbqJHC8gGkXYqOnHHFQlT161LLmNtrZqNnUgnNFri2YwOsOc4P4VXeUHJpsr5NKsG6MtngU9h7kbncM9RUCnrgUPIVJUDpShtqdKlspIXeAO2Kct0gkC5qAdCD0qm+VnDDsa4pM6EdRHcJtAJqYEMOOlYcExMmCOtbaEFFx6UIY8KPSlAUHpinKPl4pX4561ZDYq9ePWoLoZFWV+lNdA3XrTRJBagsgBPArRRCmePpVaCLa3FTu+1hmmSMlUMMCljj2Cnlgwz3pyKSB9auLIY4x7iMClmtwke49a2YLRfs4LHnFYt4zZYA8A4qxMiuNTjNp5QxuA9K427gkkLMT1PHNaF5MVZgo71TLySDkVM3YIq5nmNkUnngUgm2j5iTV0qpQ7uvWsuRC8gVT19Kzch2EN0zsVXNS2lnPd3IVQa2tM8PDy1kP8XXNdVpmiRQSBgCQPWpuaKHUwIPCLOqs/wAoz0Nb+leHIYcZAOD3FdALYlODgdsU4J5Yzn5qzu7nTCEUjOvdMVoyEQc8CoLLR9q4IGSMGugidWOGFRupDHauBVxInqzAutGUkFCOOtVJ9KkmTyyfl9a6d48nmqksJSUHHBNNsmxxl54ZZImkwpI5rmLiBoiRzjvmvXpYY5Ijk9q5jUtAWUMyDrVKREoXOAW5Kcc49jUi3LDlSfzq1caX5UzIeCD1NUpYWhboQKu5ny9zQs9clicK+4jNdLZatDIB/e681xHltKp45qfT5WgvYhI2E3Dj8atTvuTy2O9lvNwzggGqv2wRyFQCSe9WZYobiwO1xuP3cGs22QMpDnkcZpsdieS7hkHOenNZjzKrHnjtUtzanzQRnGKR7DzI+OtLmSHZlKW4U8D1qVLhlj2g43VYh0diMlSainsmicfKalzGojUt2l5Aq8umHygTinQqsUYzj86na5+TAINFx2OaBOzLin2sPmy1AJjMoAIP0q/ZoUwelcqV2dEi0lqFbnrVsqVUc8VAu9n4zT5mYLg8YFWIuxuNg70/5WxmqFvKcDNXFJ7UXRnZk6x7hkU/bn0p9sFIAbr60kwCN6Yp8w3HQI0PBpXxn6VFFOWbHX6VMygtnpVXIEWOrEfy4qu0mwAZ59adHLyM9KtEPc1klKxhM8VlXS5LGpZHY429KikHy+5FCeoM5u+Kxy/hVVpRsIAq1rVufMDc4OOlUoyCvzY6VMxRZWmYmIjgcc1Ssw325CRxmtK8UJGWA96o6bcRvdrG33icjis2Uel2dnutYyOeB0rShhaKPB6imacrLaRkcAqK0F+cHPJxQborpK6gjFA3M2T+VWTsVecA/Solxu655osO7IkHOCe9XVKgDjtVW4uIIEJJGQckelY0mrjedrnHagnmNyeQg5UdKr7zMwBrKGsrggvUJ1gI27dgetMOY3Hj+TH61XdGA65BqK11SKbAL/ia0laOROCDxSGtTlbzR2mlMmB+Vc3qli0L4I7V6UpiJ2ttz9Kq6lpsNzHuWNCcelNMUo3PKdhjGcVQuCWcHODmuu1DS3gd/wB38vPSuelhV5MAciqTMnE1dKnmMSRgkkdDmrsmn3lqDOSxVjnpWbp0ht5FbPA7V6ZozQanYqpRWyvcVtHUVjjYS1xHgjB6E1fgtdkeSc44rS1DT0tLkqiquTnAH+fSqE0pRBzjPapcR3sSpMIgBgVTupFlPHFUprolvvHAqB5WYZU1Sh1E53JrhcLkGq3TqaUrI4+Ymo51AX3p2sI5bT7mRbjYwyvrXV4xbb06gZrnLKSKVQ6jnHpWwt4ghKBuemK5I2idL1RNZX58za4/HNaErCbGO4rnVbLkituwYMFBOeKSkNrQkQbSB6VcjkwwyOKhkj2sCPSiM73Cn1oZJp5+QMvXqajhR55cN606PCI1PSUbgVPIqWUlfcnbTzbndzj6UgAYHsallvsxiNz24NVFYlt2aqMmyZwSFuV2rvFRRSBgOxqy8asmCareSV5UE/Q1qmYtFxXA7gmmtliPSoF3DqCKtAq3HWqTJZlatamWLKnkCuSmSWKXbziu+aPOc9KytTsQYt6gZz1qmk0RsYYQSxFW6kcVUi0wJMJEJ3A5q9bYeQJ3zitNrFowHHNYs0ub+j3zNAiPxgVuQzqWwDnNcPauQ2F4atOESpk7v1qEzVS0OplG4ZBFZV5e/ZYmw3TmqR1R1+U5z9aoXaPeKQx61SE5FeXVJLuQqOARgmlJ2w8cnFQjTniwQQcVYhjO3BFXYzbMl5XD4HWrMeZFIb61PcWQZtwGKh+ztGwAp2C5Wknlt2yp4rQsPETqoDioZrIvET6DNZpiC/WoaLiztLOY3Dh934Vq+cIoyDzkVxFhqPkfKSeK0H1dJIsruOeKm5ojWlMUqtuA61wWo26HVZTDwM81qSasDlWyATzVFZN5LDByaLag2iBYyDXo3gRg0QU4FcAzBcA12Pg+bZMvBxnFbxepkbniuyKSJNH1xyPXrXGzSb48d67TxXdOLePA68Vwhkbdg960RDKki5P40LgHFWPK/iPrSDYMH0PSrYkNkICdarFQwyWNSSje5xwM0IgOQKW4ziLGKcW++IHbjj86sW8pM5R8A961RqMMOmhETJHFZLMDbPKeG7V5vNfY7XGyNBpEjIxWja3PlqGFcet3vOGzitq1nBiA56UMSZ1cE/mruNSxECUGsmxlGyr0bAtxWi1RmzXMyqlRWxDzYzkZqqrZGCakjXYcqaTQr2Na4hThge1V1IXApqyFhyadkE4ojoOUkyVSSR9atR471XUBVHSpw3HFVcVrk3lq2eKgkh2fMOtKZzEM4zSiUTr0IpqQmiJGJGD1pssPmoVI4NNlUo+RV7Tgs0gVuK0jIxaOUn0uSC5DqhwGz0rVh3ybYyPwrpb6wV422gE07R9ExKJJDk+mKbSYrMzLfw1PI4kCEKcetad1pS2sG0DGB69a68yxwQBQoOBXNahIbi4wTgYqbRRephf2aGYscc0CyVGBAwK1gAODUbpwOaExJXMuaEk9OnWo/snGdlajRVIkSlecVQWMZrUjIOaqvCqtjBrfkTJ4xVaW0BBJNAGS6AxY/CsS4t9pO0HBrpZYwErMmiBzSeg0YaRlenB9agmuvs+VPQ1qNEVfAGRVXUNNaYKQvb0rK2paZhSvLcn5OBn0rXs0Ij+ar1loRaIc4b6U6bTJLZS2cgdqoDOuPl962vD921vMh6D1rMELTNgira/6KFAFWmB3948d5YDeM4Ga5HUYo0UOgwc81vaLm8tGRmxWXrdn9lmGDnPAFapkMxQrk4p5iAXng1MpUVHK/HaqEVpFxUIbaamYE9OlN8sZz3xQI465ETKwjdfQYNZUhuFJTkpjNS6TbiWTMknviugazh2YJ3ZFeVGJ6MjjPtYWfax/DFb1lJuwF5BHWp5vDsUvzoefpUUdo9nKMk8VpyWMeY6G3RlhDDNXLeU7uTWYuposCoRznFSxzbzla1SsZN3ZuIA/epULKwU9Kp2bEkDNXiOhpiJkHenCQqcCokkHQGjqaQ0i7G24+oqxGOM1TTKgVYRyAPekUi1+7bg4pUCAfLgVEuCDzTlyOMigb1CYgrjGTTLRZFkyB+tKfvc1Ytj81HMZuJ1GnrE1sDJjOPSmyTGM4Q4HasuKd14U8UO8h5BquZsTReMznIZzz71VkibcWznFRAtjJNWoASnNNDsVJmIYc0+Ib15qw9sHGTUOzyzgVdiAkhAHHWowuBz+VTDLcnpVec4GRTBIeojzyagunyMLx7VDG7tmn4LNzQBWKKVJNZlzGT9wVsTREKTmq0TxrkNjPvSYzAaTZJjvmrHm/u8Ffxqxd28ZmLLTI41dcHtU6DI4boryOBRc3BmG319qmMaEbevtSfZHSTew+XtmlylEcFk5UNs5rTh0Y3AyE5+laOmeRKoXPPetu3ntLRsMVFapElTSdP8AsUR3gAetYvihFMiNnOD/AErT13X44oysO3nmuIutRnvGzIeM54qkJjXZVGeKj83dxgUqpuUgmmlVXqeasQrgADGKiY4WlduOOwqu0pA7c0gPLobpywaJiD7HFbNjfzSTKjMxPHU1e0zQLaON2Yk8cc1C0UNteZSvJ510O+zOktmIj5HNQTW5cFjjrVSG+LkhcVcimLnawxW8JNmM42KEmn5UPnv60W8jRvj0PrV+4t5BFlDmsfc8b5I78inr1J0OktrkAjnrWwjeYnBFc3bfMoatGGcrxnirTFYu9DketSrcKOMnNUXkcg4NNgLFuaTLsbQLMB9alBOMZNUYnbHWrCuR1PFJEsuwHFPkkAqr5gxwaQuGHemTcsod2Tk1YhYhqoQvzVlZSDk0WFc0Ulwwq9CyuOlZcUgfGe9W4Tg47UIZYf8A2aInYHmpSq7aaoB6cVaHYs+ZnjoKjdR1pAcvUgQFTWqFylQybeOahlOTmpJcI/XiopJB0pE2GjA6UpfaRxmkaNtuRSEUkKw2YsUbisd4pDKcY6VpySkZX1qAnB6UxFUQORhqjkQwjGeDzWgZFC5GM45rLuyzMSo4qbDHwXSpNuOcVJe6tG4AVGJIx7VjSsy9QartIc5JyaBnW2F9Bb27E45HNczcaibjUZJMkpuO3NVJrk7MKxA7iq0c6Dgn86qO4PY12nWSPnNQhwDVeOUE5FTgoeD0rZGRKJgRiq8pC80jOB92mMpcZOCKCgWTdwKjkx37UjSCLPr0qDzcsc0nqNHC2fiJ5pCgVh8uasPeK0e3J37e/rXL6fcR28js55K4FOS7eS9XaeGYCvMlh9fdNVVdjrtHLl/mPFdHHKpcVjaXZNsEjdKLq8EE5Td3q46FO8joWnULVGQRynJ4Oayppp3jVtzbD0NRi7J43Hdn1q3K4krHRwBUT2qcMrYOKxIrk7OWNW4buPcBmki3Zm3C6sNvcUqgK+RVSCVSAc1ZaRSODg1QrluOTYfWneYzcfjVNX4yTUwkGQB1pbCbLSswxnpU4PBqCIErzVhdpXBpXIIkkAk61pIAxAyOayZVCOTU8U3zAhqpBZGsFMeGzV2JzgE1RimD7cmrbN+7460Idiz5p6ZqWIk5rOiJHU1ajn2datMrUw9VuZrjUppJVvHsbO6gsLezt7h7Y315Ku9t80W50jihYSH5QCc8nbioLJNYutSsbbR5rmztNR1F7C9iublrh9NmhHmkwyzIWkWa3RmUFSoYg5GcVJc6jFbLfXEgZY7DxFb3dyzAIscE9l9mSXc2AV83IOCSNpJHFUrvXZrfS7XVNNvraymufEc19ZXN0A8EkEFoLaRnZSQsbSYjySGxICozincybF02L+2f7Lt9Kj1LS7u7iebS76/1ae8W7ZF3CO6iwY4/Nj3vlDlSvHI2mdbi119NCfUonTSpIDrOpLhJES2gQSFWBBLDzGhBCrkjd0pNA1vQtP1eXXbPw3p1tpukxXM9zfW+oz3UEO5QTDbB0SFJneSPAQ/d3LgZFZelWjP4ZuYJbZWmuDpvhvdbzDzFES/aLtWcEbUMZZCFYlimCOlMVy94Js/7Tu7DSdau30yOS7kni0yz0+6tRN5kDTmMTo4VFRpHGzr+4HrVfTPt11a6PcXNjf6nbyaVbbcas1nEJGVmlkkePMrt8sQUYK/M5ODXS2V5Zn4g+HLFLy3e7jvZWe3WQGRB9kn5K5yByPzFcnoOrNfeHNM07S7+ztzDYwfb9UuHX7PpqFQuXJIBkJ+VY88nrgA0Aae1IjaajZR3lhnUH0m/065vXvYy4haeOaKVzuGV2gggZ3Y2grk52rW0Oo2ms3N3bJKw8nRNO+0W6zItxPiSeVVHzB0hCMrEqBhutVrTW/DEt5GLDU0ttFsGb7It1eKJby4bcst5MvDF2B2rv6LkhVyANC2hL2vhq3Nv5TNa3Gu3Hkv+7Z7yU+QW6F5FiWRCSuAOAaVxCW0MF/4ZudZn1W4k1eA6Xvso7a5s0s/NuArgqz7Zt2WTdjHye9Q3mo2cSNqusNMdLS5ls7Cwt7r7G9/cJGS8jysyFYEb5MoTl+ucBTNHqFhPo3iq5gvLeW2jOi+ZLHKrIuL1yckHAwOasxeJJtP8JeHrvTNVtLO0bUtTtrnU4hBI8LNM8scW6TIRXUbz8pzsj6ZBIIzbZ7e8nubywSGGyMccSww6tLfgSKXLNvkAKkhkG0f3c96iYEsa0Li7XUpfD+q3JiOs6jpty17IkZga7ijmRLad4s8Fk3ENjkEgcAAQ+TiTOOM0wuY9zFBJOYL7Vm0mye2lZ71bCW6KMNoAxGQV4ZjuPHy1Y8W2Gn+HvEmvWsDPDYWc8YQSzPIUBgiYjc5LHLMeM9+Kf4lurK28P38c0sEUstrKsSu4Uudp4UHqeR09a0fFGpQ6b8Y727MFlez2moRXC2VxMEL/AOhIqsPlY5ViGBx1XtSY0zOsNGt20/X01q4uodbt9CudRtdMhlaM2SqoKSXBUg+axZSIzkKudwywqv8AbA7hfKn2+b5Hm+Q/l+Zs37N+Nu7bzjOcV0Hh/UPD0c/iaU+DhDK+h311dP8A23cXBukGwyIxdRtL5HzjJ4rkLSeaON4RJeRacdVkuI7fa00Ec5iIVPtDR7mZYSBgtzjOKqLJZtPJ4e0Xwzot7qWktfXepTX5eabXbizRRDcbFAC5H3WHAA+73qlZC1lTU9furKddEjvYbXTtKg1SZxdXEkSlw1yAZAiJul+6AS2MnGDJp/jrWNEsUtdE12cOsomttLms0YztK3mhApjErLJ5nBDdGBBrZ8TR6Np+m+IrLQ0gSz0jxPDdXUUDAR2yTWghzknGPPLqVX7uDwAKBmFewQG1tda0uK4trC6uZbG5spZ2n+xXUa7lCyyYd0kiG/oQD35wKokYscdq0HmQ+BLFSD/xMPEM95a4+YSQQ2vkPJlcgDzMAZwTkEDFUBtQE4q47Bc8kRGdtqjJrUtNHud6y4+6QQMVTsJ1t7pZHGQPbNdpp/iG0Zkjzg+m2uOtOcfhRrTgpbkK6vPbwFGUcdqzo7l727JPrWlrLrL8yDj+dZulxhZckcZrGOurNmraHTOVFh5YGcVz7RStMcEj6VtGcbdq9TToYCpLMK2SBiaZbuSFlzzW0NNjBBDHNYsurJb3ATn0rQGuQLGC2RVqxJpGHyAPSkVg3eqLaks8I25qGKciTaelPQhm6OlKrc571FAxdRmnNwKliLyXBA604XB3cVQUmrUDDgNSGiwXMgwR+VNBMb5pQ4Q8etMmOPmHenaxVjShkygYVoRTFhg4rEtJgAATV0SAtxVboLWNFWC9TmlM69KrIcjrSkhevWkOw17TOqwapZ3lxYajAjRrdW23c0bdY3DqysucEAg4IBGDUM2k/bb2bULrUr241SR4WW/l8syRCJ1dFRQmxV3LuIC8kknNWRJxnJojkIfk4o5hchJdWVxqd1aXGs6xe6mtm5kt4bhYljSQ8CTbGihmAzgtnGTjBNZWiW93MdH+3WkkQ0uyl+e6WJpJLy5k8y4dTGxCoNoC8A4c5rRuOmQajjyoOTVcxHKWI/7SsLm8k0zXL+yS7lE0sUUdu67wipkb4mP3UXvVf7RrsOoT6gnifUvtM0UcMj+Ra/MiFyox5OODI/5+woNycUu8lckc01qS0ZniQ65ruiS6bqGuanqFjNLD9oto4rSN3jEqM21vLXDAAkcgZAzxxU8cs97rGra1dWy29xqN0XEe1Q6RIojiViGYE7EDHBxlmxT5JgAR3qMSEDJzTsCRJZX3iHS9PtrCz8TahHaWsSQwp5Fq21FACjJhycADrWfp1veaPf3Oo6Zq99aX12Xa7njWI/aWZy+50ZCmQWbBCggEjpWkuHUH161D3IFVYgprHN9tmurq9ur68n4knupS7EbmYKBwqKC7YVQAM9KlO3HXmpniA5PArJuJgGGPXmiwEjX93pt+l/p2oXFldxxPDviSNtyOUJBEiMOqL0qpqeua5riW6arrNzeQ28vnRxvDAgD7WTOUjU9HbvVjKSRk98VnTMFByaVgK7vMouBb3sts1xaS2U3lqh8yGTbvU7lOM7RyMH3rOuLm6trT7ILqT7D9s+2fZ9qbfO8vyt2du77vGM49qtYO/PWi6jSS2IYDNCVtRWuSaf4z8Q2ehrpNn4jv4LFIzDHGoiLRoc/KsjIXGAcA7sqAMEYFQ6dqM2mammqabqFzaagvmbrlHEjyByWcP5gYOCx3fMDzgjmudkhMcm3tTWUryDTUkFjp72/utS1WTU9QvZr6+kRYzPNtBVB0RQoCqucnAAySScmmlyyHtXOW2oENtYng+laq3Kuo+Y1rFk6n/9k=</Image>

 </somenamespace>
```

I am writing an asp.net app that just displays the actual image to the browser. First question is why is the image stored as such a randomly long string? Second question how would i render the actual image in an asp.net web app - is it even possible?

Comment: "Why is the image stored"  XML is text. How else would it be stored? Ask whoever created that file what encoding was used, although it looks like BASE64. *Check the XSD*, read the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a Base64 encoded string. You can display it in HTML by appropriately setting your `src` attribute:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" />
```

Comment: how would i pass this from c# to the aspx page because the value comes from an xml file?

Comment: It depends on your application, but your Controller or code behind (depending on if you're using MVC or WebForms) can consume this XML, extract the value (XmlDocument DOM selection, for example), and then either put it in the ViewBag or set the value of the control in the code behind... Again it all depends on how you are processing the XML in your web application, and what your tech stack is.

Answer (score 1):

1. The binary sequence for the image can't be safely stored in the XML file due it's text nature, so it's converted to a base64 string.
2. Yes, most browsers can show that kind of data; take a look into this question for more background: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: why is it converted to base64? can you explain to a real beginner

Comment: @user8132396, the XML is a text file, you can't add binary content. Open an image on the notepad and you'll understand that. We must encode the binary values into a text representation, and that is the _base64 encoding_.